# Javascript Mailto without Href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have requirement where clicked on link it should open the mail to be sent the user on whose name i clicked. i am doing it by constructing the Anchor tag and by setting the href attribute, problem i am facing is , our platform has a function which shows alert asking do you want to navigate or no. this alert should not come when i click on my link, but unfortunately it comes when i clicked on link. is there alternative for this? 
[Note : i cannot change the platform code]

```
var htmlElement = $('<a class="b">('+_email+')</a>').attr('href','mailto:'+_email);
```

i also tried jquery click , but no use

```
$('.b').click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    }).click();
```

Comment: What is generating this `alert`? Can you disable it for non-http/https protocols?

Comment: after you have bound your platform function, why not just add code to unbind it for that anchor

Comment: Will adding a `target="_blank"` to your anchor work?

Comment: this alter is happening cos, href mostly trying to navigate from window, whenever page is navigated this alter pops up.

Comment: adding target="_blank" worked fine. do you have any explanation on this?

Comment: i do have some problem when using target="_blank" , it opens new window with email address, also open the mail box. but it should not open the window with email address.

Comment: In your case the alert is popping up because of `onbeforeunload`. So, clicking on an anchor will cause the page to navigate away and hence the event handler is called. By using `target="_blank"`, you are not navigating away, but opening a new window instead thereby bypassing your `onbeforeunload`. If you do not want a new window, then @epascarello solution would best fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code that does the onbeforeunload checking. Normally it is done with a flag that you can set.

You can override the onbeforeunload and reapply it after the link is clicked.

**Example:**

**HTML**

```
<a class="mail" href="mailto:foo@example.com">Mail</a>
<br/>
<a href="example.com">Link</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};

$(".mail").on("click", function () {
   var _onbeforeunload = window.onbeforeunload;
    window.onbeforeunload = $.noop;
    window.setTimeout( function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = _onbeforeunload;
    },20);
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/vE9E6/

Comment: can you please tell me what is $.noop , cos its throwing error.

Comment: Not sure why it would be throwing an error. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/ You can replace it with `window.onbeforeunload = function(){};` What version of jQuery are you using that it is throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

You just need one simple change to your code...

```
$(document).on("click", "a.b", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href);
});
```

That stops the default action caused by clicking the link, and then uses `window.open` to open the mailto link in a new window, rather than changing the location.  This will stop the `onbeforeunload` event firing.

Comment: the element that's anchor tag are constructed dynamically. and click function are not getting called. i changed to "On" still it doesn't get called and alert pops up.

Comment: No worries - a small change should fix that.  The event handler is now assigned to the document, but only runs for anchors with class `b`.  Ideally, change document to a closer container.